# FFMPEG: How do I convert a minute long MP4 into a WebM (VP8) under 4MB with a decent quality?

Tags: ffmpeg, webm, video-compression

I've seen people on 4chan posting 2-3 minutes long file with a decent quality with sound on /wsg/ or /gif/. I tried to do the same with my MP4 file which is a minute long with this command:

> ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -threads 4 -c:v libvpx -c:a libvorbis -b:v 400k -b:a 128k -quality good -qmin 0 -qmax 55 output.webm

The source video was 12MB and the resulting video was around 4.7MB. But video quality was not so great. I tried changing some of the values which would give me a video under 4MB but with a bad picture quality. How do I find the sweet spot between the size and the quality? Pls help.

Comment: Why do you want VP8 instead of VP9?

Comment: 4chan doesn't support VP9

Comment: See [FFmpeg Wiki: VP8](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/VP8).